# Defining implicit view-bounds on Scala traits

Tags: scala, generics, types

I'm doing an exercise to implement a functional binary-search-tree in Scala, following a similar pattern that I've seen used in Haskell. I have a structure that looks something like this:

```
trait TreeNode[A] {
    def isLeaf: Boolean
    def traverse: Seq[A]
    ...
}

case class Branch[A](value: A, left: TreeNode[A], right: TreeNode[A]) extends TreeNode[A] { 
   def isLeaf: Boolean = false
   def traverse: Seq[A] = ...
   ... 
}

case class Leaf[A]() extends TreeNode[A] { 
    def isLeaf: Boolean = true
    def traverse: Seq[A] = Seq[A]()
    ... 
}
```

I'd ***like*** to put a type constraint on `A` so that it will only accept objects that extend `Ordered`. It looks like I need to define a view bound on A *(`[A <% Ordered[A]]`)* on `Branch` and `Leaf`, as well as the `TreeNode` trait.. I can't do this on the `TreeNode` trait, however, because view bounds aren't accepted.

As I understand, `<%`-style view-bounds are syntactic sugar for an `implicit` definition, so there should be a way to write to define the bound manually within the `TreeNode` trait. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do this, though. I've looked around a bit, but haven't gotten much further than that some sort of implicit needs to be defined.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? Am I approaching this from the wrong angle entirely?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is that view bounds as well as context bounds are just syntactic sugar for specific types of implicit parameters. When applied to a type parameter of a generic class (as opposed to when applied to a generic method), these implicits are added to the constructor of the class.
Because traits have no constructor (or rather, only have a single **parameterless** constructor), there is nowhere to pass these implicit parameters and thus context bounds and view bounds are illegal on generic traits.
The simplest solution would be to turn `TreeNode` into an abstract class.:

```
abstract class TreeNode[A <% Ordered[A]]
```

Note that as advised by Ben James, using a context bound with an `Ordering` is usually better than a view bound with an `Ordered` (it is more general). However the problem is still the same: won't work on a trait.

If turning `TreeNode` into a class is not practical (say you need to mix it at various places in the type hierarchy), you can define an abstract method in `TreeNode` that will provide the implicit value (of type `Ordered[A]`) and have all the classes that extend it define it. This unfortunately more verbose and explicit, but you can't do much better in this case:

```
trait TreeNode[A] {
  implicit protected def toOrdered: A => Ordered[A]
}

case class Branch[A<%Ordered[A]](value: A, left: TreeNode[A], right: TreeNode[A]) extends TreeNode[A] { 
   protected def toOrdered = implicitly[A => Ordered[A]]
}

case class Leaf[A<%Ordered[A]]() extends TreeNode[A] { 
    protected def toOrdered = implicitly[A => Ordered[A]]
}
```

Note that for a more concise definition, you could equivalently define `Leaf` like this:

```
case class Leaf[A](implicit protected val toOrdered: A => Ordered[A]) extends TreeNode[A]
```

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a go (with an abstract class `TreeNode[A: Ordering]`) when I get a chance.

Comment: Marking this as accepted, because I think your edit actually answered the question I was originally trying to ask, in addition to also giving good advice on how to avoid this issue. Thanks.

Comment: A slight correction: Traits permit no _constructor parameters_, they do yield (non-default) constructors when they include concrete `val`s.

Comment: This is very true, saying that traits have no constructor is a rather loose description of the reality. I'll update the phrasing.

Comment: @Régis Jean-Gilles can we implement the `implicitly[A => Ordered[A]]` in trait itself, so that we dont have to implement every where we are extending the trait.

Comment: No because `implicitly[T]` captures the implicit value of type `T` (if any) that is in scope at that point. So you'll end up capturing an implicit value of type `A => Ordered[A]`, which is bound to fail because most likely what you have is several implicit values such as `Int => Ordered[Int]` of `Float => Ordered[Float]` (in other words, with a specific type `A`) rather than a generic method returning an instance of `A => Ordered[A]` (otherwise there would be no point in using a type class in the first place, as the purpose is precisely to specialize behaviour depending on the type).

Answer (score 16):

You could provide the "evidence" that `A` is `Ordered` by requiring an abstract member of type `Ordered[A]` on the `trait`:

```
trait TreeNode[A] {
  implicit val evidence: Ordered[A]
}
```

You would then be forced to provide this in any concrete subtypes, this proving that `A` is `Ordered`:

```
case class Leaf[A](value: A)(implicit ev: Ordered[A]) extends TreeNode[A] {
  val evidence = ev
}
```

---

You might instead want to constrain `A` to a type which has an implicit `Ordering[A]` - this is not an inheritance relationship; it is more like a haskell typeclass. But the implementation in terms of the above technique would be the same.

Comment: I actually did try that. It compiles correctly, but chokes up on trying to pass it, say, an Int. `error: type arguments [Int] conform to the bounds of none of the overloaded alternatives of ...`. That's what led me to looking into <%.

Comment: In response to your edit, it looks like Scala also doesn't allow context bounds on traits: `error: traits cannot have type parameters with context bounds ':...' nor view bounds '<% ...' trait TreeNode[A: Ordering]`

Comment: I will agree that what I'm looking for is more along the lines of a Haskell typeclass, or interface in most Object Oriented languages, and I probably just don't understand what the equivalent is for Scala.

Comment: My bad, I edited that first part out before reading your comment.

Comment: Funny, your last edit with `implicit val evidence` is exactly the same as the edit I was writing at the same time. Great minds and all that :)

Comment: To be honest, I'd never noticed that you couldn't use view or context bounds on the type of a `trait`, hence me quickly rewriting this after actually trying it out on the REPL and realising what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

[@ben-james](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189179/ben-james)'s answer is great, I would like improve it a bit to avoid redundant `val`s in classes.

The idea is to define implicit constructor parameter name the same as it is defined in trait that holds implicit value.

The idea is to avoid this line:

```
val evidence = ev
```

Here is a complete example ([gist](https://gist.github.com/Abrasha/0629a8e96292db75f898c80512e0d857))

```
trait PrettyPrinted[A] extends (A => String)

object PrettyPrinted {
  def apply[A](f: A => String): PrettyPrinted[A] = f(_)
}

trait Printable[A] {
  implicit def printer: PrettyPrinted[A]
}

// implicit parameter name is important
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
                 (implicit val printer: PrettyPrinted[Person])
  extends Printable[Person]

object Person {
  implicit val printer: PrettyPrinted[Person] =
    PrettyPrinted { p =>
      s"Person[name = ${p.name}, age = ${p.age}]"
    }
}

// works also with regular classes
class Car(val name: String)
         (implicit val printer: PrettyPrinted[Car])
  extends Printable[Car]

object Car {
  implicit val printer: PrettyPrinted[Car] =
    PrettyPrinted { c =>
      s"Car[name = ${c.name}]"
    }
}
```