# How to define a trait so that we extend with classes that have context bounds?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Suppose I want to be able to do:

```
trait MyTrait[T: Numeric] {
  val numeric = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
  import numeric.mkNumericOps
  // more code
}
```

Then extend with

```
class MyClass[T: Numeric] extends MyTrait[T] {
  // code
}
```

You get ye old "traits cannot have type parameters with context bounds".

Is there something that is syntactically very close to this, and does the same thing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Defining implicit view-bounds on Scala traits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483732/defining-implicit-view-bounds-on-scala-traits)

Comment: The question isn't quite the same due view-bounds being an implicit conversion rather than implicit object.  Though this answer is *nearly* the same as one would ideally want http://stackoverflow.com/a/14484103/1586965

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
trait MyTrait[T] {
  val numeric: Numeric[T]
  import numeric.mkNumericOps
  // more code
}

class MyClass[T: Numeric] extends MyTrait[T] {
  val numeric = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
  // code
}
```